# highest power of x of a number k that is less than n

Tags: functions

For this code:

```
   a = IntegerExponent[k,7]; (*a is highest power of 7 that divides k*)
```

I would like to find b, where b is:

```
   b = IntegerPower[k,7]; (*b is highest power of 7 that is less than k*)
```

Is there an efficient way to implement a function to do that?

cheers,
Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IntegerPower[k_, b_] := If[IntegerQ[#], # - 1, Floor[#]] &@Rationalize[Log[b, k]];
```

**Examples**

```
IntegerPower[345, 7] (* Outputs 3 *)
IntegerPower[0.0028, 7] (* Outputs -4 *)
IntegerPower[100, 2] (* Outputs 6 *)
IntegerPower[0.5, 2] (* Outputs -2 *)
```

Comment: Imo this function is a candidate for the Wolfram Function Repository. Although modified to (*b is highest power of 7 that is less than =or equal= to k*). As it is quite often used.